# What does this icon mean in Pidgin's buddy list?

Tags: icons, pidgin

What does this icon mean in Pidgin's buddy list?

[image]

I can't figure it out. **No specific tool-tip appears when hovering the mouse pointer over it**, only the status of the user, which appears when you hover the mouse pointer over any user.

Comment: Hover over it. You should see a tooltip. Or just, click it.

Comment: In the question I explained *"No specific tool-tip appears when hovering the mouse pointer over it, only the status of the user, which appears when you hover the mouse pointer over any user."*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that you are blocking the user.

Source: https://developer.pidgin.im/wiki/Using%20Pidgin#Whatdotheiconsnexttomybuddymean

Comment: So the user doesn't see me but I see him/her?